# Add listview items to a list of object in Entity Framework database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF application. I did the database with Entity Framework code first. 
I have a listview populated with some object as follow:

```
private void lstDishes_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var item = lstViewDishes.SelectedItem as Dish;
   lstViewOrder.Items.Add(item);
 }
```

Now I have to save into my database the items in this listview and I was trying to do:

```
Order or = new Order();
or.Server = cBoxServer.SelectedItem as Server;
foreach (ListViewItem item in lstViewOrder.Items)
{
   or.Dishes.Add(item);     //this is not working
}
```

Relationship between `Order` and `Dish` is many-to-many. Then items in listview have to be stored in the `IList<Dish>` in `Order` class and, then, in database.

How can I reach this?

Comment: @Sajeetharan can't convert from ListViewItem to Dish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**,

> Rather than looping over ListViewItem, since you already have a
>   lstViewOrder, you can do this

```
    foreach (Dish item in lstViewOrder.Items)
    {
       or.Dishes.Add(item);   
    }
```

Comment: No, now says that Dish is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: check the modified one

Comment: Sorry again, I just tried to add the new Order to my database, but I'm getting an exception in the same part.

Comment: It is a Null Reference Exception